# Android: Load the activity after accessing the notification bar

Tags: android, android-notifications

if there is no internet means I'm not able to load web resources. For this reason I'm giving the toast like "Check internet connectivity". After this toast, user may enable the internet option at notification bar and comes back. When he comes back, i want to reload the activity. For this requirement, i tried

```
onWindowFocusChanged and onActivityReenter
```

override methods but these are not working properly

**MyCode**

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(hasFocus){
            Intent intent = new Intent(CommonActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);  
    }
}
```

When I'm using above code, my activity reloading again and again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By fallowing another way (i got this idea when i saw the flipkart app) i solved this internet checking

1. I'm checking for the internet connection, if there is no internet means i'm redirecting to NoInternetActivity that's design looks like

[image]

2. When user clicks on Retry button means i'm again checking for internet. If internet was accessible means i'm allowing user to home page of my app otherwise i'm redirecting to the NoInternetActivity again

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution which i know is not perfect but it will work.
Define a activity level veriable like this

```
Boolean isAlreadyFocused = false;
```

Then in your onFocusChanged method do like this.

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
   super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(hasFocus && !isAlreadyFocused ){
        isAlreadyFocused = true;
        Intent intent = new Intent(CommonActivity.this,OtherActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);  
  }else{
     isAlreadyFocused = false;
    }
}
```

Check this and tell me if this does not work.

Comment: Hi Arslan. I already tried this one. By using this also my activity reloading again and again